# combining the gq command

Tags: key-bindings

I was wondering if it is possible to combine the `gq` operation with other commands, as one might do with the `|` operator. For example, it would be nice to be able to write a command like `:'<,'>left4 |gq`. However, vim says that `gq` in this context is not an editor command, because it is interpreting it as `:gq`. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run normal mode commands from the command-line with the `:normal` command.

In this instance, we want to first reselect the visual selection, and then run the `gq` command:

```
:'<,'>left4 | norm! gvgq
```

See `:help :normal` and `:help gv` for more details.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a global search & replace  so you reindent as you go?

Comment: @Steve You mean something like this? `:%s/foo/bar/g | norm! gggqG`

Comment: Doh of course I forgot the go to beginning bit. Thanks